# Is there an application for HR Management in ubuntu?

Tags: package-management

Is there an application available in Ubuntu that can :

- Keeps attendance details of the employees.
- Overtime hours
- Can make salary of employees.

It should be easy to use than Libre Calc.

Comment: You mean you mean an application for HR?

Comment: Something like that. But not need much deep. Simple one that can input data about attendance, OT hours and then can make the salary depending on such data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find many applications that serve your needs. The most known are:

**1- OrangeHRM**

It is the world's most popular and used open source human resource management software.

The open source OrangeHRM product suite includes an array of modules that provide personal information management (PIM), employee self-service (ESS), leave management, time and attendance tracking (PTO), performance evaluation and recruitment, all at no cost.

Today OrangeHRM is being used by over a million users around the world, while larger multinationals have used the open source version and customized the system to meet their human resource management standards & requirements.

***Features Include:***

- Personal Information Management
- AdancedLeave Management
- Time & Attendance Tracking
- Employee Performance Management
- Recruitment
- Advanced Reporting

To know more about its features check [this.](http://www.orangehrm.com/Features.html)

You can download from [here](http://www.orangehrm.com/download.php)

**2- ICeHRM**

ICeHRM is a free and open source web based Human Resource Management system developed targeting small and medium sized companies to restructure their HRM process around it.

With a rich AJAX user interface, ICeHRM gives the user an experience similar to using a desktop application.

***Features include:***

- Administration: define departments, job titles, pay grades, education information
  and other master data
- Employee Information management - contains information about employee
- Leave Management - allows HR Managers to define leave types, leave
  quota for each employee, working days and special holidays
- Attendance and Time Tracking - allows HR Managers and Supervisors to
  monitor punch in/out times for employees and manage timesheets.
  Employees can use this module to submit daily punch in/out times and
  timesheets
- Timesheet submission
- Punch In/Out time submission
- Store project and customer information
- Store employee pictures
- Automated installation
- Language support for English, Spanish, Portuguese, French, Arabic,
  Russian and Indonesian

you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icehrm/)

**3-LATRIX**

The LATRIX is an Human Resource support web application.

This software provides presence and attendance recording, attendance tracking, paperless leave applications (with freely definable leave types), block periods, a fire register and extensive reporting options.

The LATRIX was developed in close cooperation with a real company that has between 50 and 100 employees. This company still uses the LATRIX every day.

***Features include:***

- Records presence of people
- Print barcoded ID cards for staff (there is a report for this) and
  once you have set up a PC with an internet connection and a barcode
  scanner, they simply scan the barcode when the arrive at the company
  and when they leave
- Records attendance at work for staff
- Employees can indicate to the system whether they are starting or
  stopping work,
- going on a break or coming back or whether they are transferring
  between sites
- Reduces HR administration work load
- Multiple locations
- Multiple time zones
- Automates employee requests for leave
- Public holidays
- Block periods, where no annual leave can be taken or when leave
  applications have to be escalated to the next level of management for
- Handles shifts and shift patterns
- Organization structure
- Reduces paper work
- Powerful reports
- Empowers staff
- Enforces work flow

you can download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latrix/).

You can also take a look on [WaypointHR](http://waypointhr.com).

Comment: @DuminduMahawela You are very welcome my friend. I'll edit my answer to inform you about more light HR applications

Comment: Ok. Better that others can get from this. For me, this more than enough.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela ok friend. Good to be able to serve you.